# MuseScore: Change all notes to auto velocity

Tags: software, dynamics, musescore

In MuseScore, you change the velocity (volume) of a note by right-clicking it, selecting <kbd>note properties</kbd> and changing the velocity. I want to make the velocity type on all of the notes <kbd>auto</kbd> (somehow, I don't know how, they're all set to <kbd>user</kbd> at 110 velocity). I could manually go through each note and reset the velocity to <kbd>auto</kbd>. However, with five staves and 100+ measures, it's not really practical to change each note to <kbd>auto</kbd> one by one. Even if I selected multiple notes at a time, it would still be tedious and time consuming.

Is there any practical way to change all of the notes in a score to <kbd>auto</kbd> velocity?

Comment: Sorry I'm not answering your question but you can find all the help on the MuseScore forum at http://musescore.org/en/forum Repost your question there and you'll find that the MuseScore community is very friendly and helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After an hour or so of composing and trying different things, I found my solution:

1. Right click any note head and click <kbd>Select</kbd> > <kbd>All Similar Elements</kbd>
2. Right click any note and select <kbd>Note Properties...</kbd>
3. Set velocity type to <kbd>auto</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Comment: This answer from 9 years ago was my salvation today, thank you so much for this, @American Luke from the past :) There were some changes in current version. For point 2, go to View > Object Controller (F8). For point 3, find "Playback" section and reset velocity type and value

Comment: I am using MuseScore 3.6.2 and I don't see an Object Controller, but I do see an Inspector, but then, it has Velocity as "Offset" or "User" and it can be set to a hard value or I suppose if it is Offset, that means a delta (plus or minus the value)... but I don't see an auto there